# Emulate jQuery .detach() in older version?

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery 1.3.2 and currently I'm not in a position where I can hope for an upgrade. Consider this code that works in 1.4.2:

```
var some_elem = $('#some_element');
var other_elem = $('#other_element');
some_elem.detach();
other_elem.replaceWith(some_elem);
```

How should I rewrite this code to make it work in jQuery 1.3.2? It doesn't implement the `.detach()` method.

Comment: Upgrades are free and _really_ easy. Rather than spending time on this nonsense, I suggest spending time removing your ridiculous technical block.

Comment: @Tom from personal experience, at some companies the IT managers are not the smartest people on earth, if you know what I mean. So, this is valid question.

Comment: @Shadow: When developing web applications, and choosing which Javascript files to include in your code, IT managers should have pretty much _nothing_ to do with it. And if your software development manager won't let you upgrade from jQuery 1.3.2 (which is [2½ years old](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery#Release_history)), then it's time for a new job.

Comment: @Tom I'm totally with you, but yes such people exist and they sit in their chair, taking big part of the company income and block any upgrade because they think it's too risky.

Answer (score 3):

[`detach` *<sup>[source]</sup>*](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L272) is calling [`remove` *<sup>[source]</sup>*](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L155) but sets a special flag to *not* delete all the data jQuery is using internally and was attached via `data()`.

Aprat from clearing the data, `remove` is only doing the following to remove the element:

```
elem.parentNode.removeChild( elem );
```

You could create your own plugin:

```
(function($) {
    if(!$.fn.detach) {
        $.fn.detach = function() {
            return this.each(function() {
                if(this.parentNode) {
                    this.parentNode.removeChild( this );
                }
            });
       };
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Isn't this backwards? [`.detach()` _doesn't_ remove jQuery data](http://api.jquery.com/detach/).

Comment: @Tomalak: Yes, forgot the not :) Thanks.

Comment: Teehee... Forget me not forget the not.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd fake `.detach` like this when (a) it doesn't do what `.detach` does (and is thus misnamed), and (b) it does exactly what `.remove` already does (and is thus needless).

Comment: @Tomalak: You said yourself, that `remove` is clearing the data. `detach` does not and this is the only difference between them. `detach` is effectively what I posted above.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation for [`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/):

> The `.detach()` method is the same as `.remove()`, except that `.detach()`
>   keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This
>   method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the
>   DOM at a later time.

"All jQuery data" means all bound events and `.data()` items.

If you don't care about this, use [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove), which has existed in jQuery since version 1.0.